# setting up JIRA so it reports its hostname properly

Tags: configuration, hostname, jira

I'm evaluating JIRA for task/bug tracking. Looks good so far but it keeps reporting URLs with "localhost" rather than the server name in outgoing email messages. (example below) Is there a way to fix this?

> ### dollar bills wear out too fast
>
> ```
>              Key: TWEEDLEDEE-2
>              URL: http://localhost:8082/browse/TWEEDLEDEE-2
>          Project: Tweedledee
>       Issue Type: Whiz-bang-thingamajig!
>       Components: Dee
>      Environment: USA money
>         Reporter: Jason S (admin)
>         Assignee: Jason S
> ```
>
> dollar bills just wear out too fast.
>   find a solution please.
>
> --  This message is automatically generated by JIRA.
>   - If you think it was sent incorrectly contact one of the administrators:
>   http://localhost:8082/secure/Administrators.jspa
>   - For more information on JIRA, see: http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out myself.

You go to Administration → Global Settings → General Configuration → Edit Configuration (at bottom... NOTE: this does not have an underline to indicate it's a link) → Base URL

Answer (score 1):

JIRA doesn't officially support putting tomcat behind apache unless you use `mod_proxy_http`. In addition to setting the `Base URL` property in the admin screens, the recommended configuration goes something like this

`/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/jira.company.com.conf`

```
...
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location />
   ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
...
```

`/opt/j2ee/domains/company.com/jira/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

```
...
<Connector address="localhost" port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
   enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
   debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000"
   proxyName="jira.company.com" proxyPort="80"
   disableUploadTimeout="true" /> 
...
```

This should get your going on `http`, let me know if you want an example for `https`

*disclaimer: I am currently an Atlassian employee, although I don't work on the JIRA team*